# Setting Icon for PyInstaller Application

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have been all over Google, Reddit, StackOverflow, PyInstaller docs, I can't figure this out.

I'm trying to set my icon for my application, but it will not work. The icon is applied to the main exe, however, the icon does not show in the taskbar when it is open for Windows.

The icon is being included. I have set the value icon in EXE directly to the icon path. I have used **Resource Hacker**, I have used **RCEDIT**, which by the way, kills my application entirely. I, for the life of me, **CANNOT** get the icon of the application to show correctly.

I have tried Windows 10 and Windows 7.

Even when I run Pyinstaller without -F, it still won't load the icon. I'm 100% certain my file is an .ico file, and includes multiple acceptable sizes, Resource Hacker showed all acceptable sizes for the .ico.

---

- [Title Bar of the App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSVpM.png)
- [App with the right icon, in the directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwfB6.png)
- [App icon on the taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11xvw.png)

---

Here is the powershell command I'm using:

```
pyinstaller -F -i C:\aNote\theme\anoteicon.ico --clean anotemain.spec
```

Here is my .spec

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['anotemain.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\aNote'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('c:\\aNote\\theme\\anoteicon.png','theme'), 
             ('c:\\aNote\\theme\\kabook.png','theme'), 
             ('c:\\aNote\\theme\\Python.svg.png','theme'), 
             ('c:\\aNote\\theme\\anoteicon.ico','.'), 
             ('c:\\aNote\\anoteui.py','.'),
             ('c:\\aNote\\version.txt','.')],
             hiddenimports=["PyQt5.sip", "QtGui", "QtWidgets", "pyperclip", "webbrowser", "csv"],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='aNote',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          clean=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False,
          icon='c:\\aNote\\theme\\anoteicon.ico',
          version='version.txt')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this command?

`Pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=app.ico app.py`

Update your .specfile and set console = **True**

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='aNote',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=False,
      clean=True,
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=True,
      icon='c:\\aNote\\theme\\anoteicon.ico',
      version='version.txt')
```

Use the sample code you can run a window UI instead of console:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
mainwindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
mainwindow.show()

app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('your.ico'))
mainwindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('your.ico'))
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I certainly have.

Comment: It worked, however, I don't want the console window open. I want it hidden. How can we achieve that?

Comment: @AQuick Easy, You can use PyQt5 to create a frame then you can hidden the console. I will post the code in my answer.

Comment: You're recommendation didn't work. However, it sparked an idea in my head.

I assigned a .png file to the window icon, instead of the actually .ico file. Changed it from the .png to .ico, problem solved.

Comment: for me to get the icon to work I had to wrap the icon path in a list, so I had `icon=['c:\\my\\file\\path\\icon.ico']`,

Answer (score 5):

Go in CMD to folder with your script ( `cd /Project` )
If your folder in d:, firsly `d:` then `cd /Project`

Enter  `pyinstaller -w -F -i "icon.ico" script.py`

Or if you app is console then `pyinstaller -F -i "icon.ico" script.py`

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by using the command `-i` instead of `--icon`

```
python -m PyInstaller --onefile -i='.\angular.ico' --name "MyApp" ".\main.py"
```

Answer (score -1):

**Simple and fast solution:**

Suppose you are using:

> Pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=app.ico app.py

But Pyinstaller not manage **taskbar** icon.

Replace icon file for taskbar in your venv, example:

> C:\python\venv\myproj311-32\Lib\site-packages\pygame\pygame_icon.bmp

**No extra dependencies**, no edit .spec

Comment: Hello to the minus man, it's good that you all know